# Swift Firestore UITableView cellForRowAt downloadURL wrong cell in closure

Tags: swift, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

Why is it that inside of a UITableView cellForRowAt that the cell reference is getting messed up when calling:
(cell is dequed from

```
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "venuepostcell")as? VenuePostTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell()}

cell.tag = indexPath.row

sRef.downloadURL { downloadURL, error in
    if downloadURL != nil {
        print ("=== A \(indexPath.row)  \(cell.tag)")
        }
    }
```

cell.tag should always equal indexPath.row.

Initially, it does, but if I do a refresh at times indexPath.row does NOT equal cell.tag???

Initial

```
===  3  3
===  0  0
===  1  1
===  2  2
===  4  4
```

and yet on refresh it will come back as

```
===  0  0
===  1  1
===  4  0 <-- WRONG
===  4  4
===  3  3
===  3  1 <-- WRONG
===  2  2
===  1  3 <-- WRONG
===  0  4 <-- WRONG
===  4  0 <-- WRONG
```

Comment: Cells are recycled by the system and the `downloadURL` is an asynchronous call -- I'm not surprised it leads to unexpected results trying to mix the two. I'd suggest you move the downloading out of the cell's logic and put it in a separate location. The cell's should just be responsible for displaying data and not *also* doing async calls to a server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how the UITableView is implemented. `sRef.downloadURL` is an asynchronous call, which means that for the time the callback is received there is a possibility that the user scrolled the table view and a brand new tag is set for the cell, while the `indexPath.row` was unchanged.

You may have to change the approach by which you are implementing this.

Comment: Thanks.  I knew that cell was reused but forgot that you can not use it inside of a async.  I refactored and got my values needed by the time that cellForRowAt get called or fill in the cell value with nil.  Works.. Thanks for the reminder!